# Incorrect execution of expression function type

Tags: python

I wrote a small python program
After entering student grades
If you enter -1
The program automatically calculates the number of students
Student grades and student average grades
But an error message occurred in the program execution error
Make it impossible to execute

```py
   avg=sum1/(len(score)-1)
TypeError: object of type'int' has no len()
```

I hope I can ask everyone for help
My code:

```py
stu=list()
sum1=0
while True:
     score=int(input("Please enter the student's score:"))
     if score==-1:
         break
     stu.append(score)
     sum1+=score
print("Total",len(stu),"students")
avg=sum1/(len(score)-1)
print("Class total score",str(sum1),"points",", average grade:",str(avg),"points")
```

Thank you everyone

Comment: You are calculating the average using `score` but instead you should be using the number of students. Try this instead `avg=sum1/(len(stu))`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake you were doing is that you are trying to get `len` of score which you converted to an integer. Instead, replace `len(score)` with `len(stu)`.

But I suggest an improved version for this code. Here instead of entering scores one after another, you have to enter them separated by a space.

```
student_scores = list(map(int(input("Please enter the scores of the students each separated by a space:\n"))))

average = sum(student_scores) / len(student_scores)

print(f"Class total score: {sum(student_scores)} points")
print(f"Class average score: {average} points")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
students = []
sum1 = 0

while True:
    score = int(input("Enter student score: "))

    if score == -1:
        break

    else:
        students.append(score)
        sum1 += score

average = sum1/(len(students) - 1)

# 'f' string allows you to put any type value inside a string including integers
print(f"Students: {len(students)}")
print(f"Class total score: {sum1} points")
print(f"Average grade: {average} points")
```

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to take the length from `int`, I assume you don't need to use `len()` there

try:
`avg=sum1/(score-1)`
or:
`avg=sum1/(len(stu)-1)`